# Trying to add schema with Datomisca results in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, datomic, datomisca

I'm trying to [get started](https://dwhjames.github.io/datomisca/doc/getstarted.html) with Datomisca, but the getting started code results in an `NoSuchMethodError`.

Here's a compact snippet that reproduces that.

```
package tw.txstream.flinktest

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import datomisca._

object DatomicTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val uri = "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/test"

    // ensure clean DB
    println("Deleted DB? " + Datomic.deleteDatabase(uri))
    println("Created DB? " + Datomic.createDatabase(uri))
    implicit val conn = Datomic.connect(uri)

    Datomic.transact(Schema.txDataA) map { tx =>
      println("Transacted")
    }
  }
}

object Schema {
  object ns {
    val ns1 = Namespace("ns1")
  }
  val attr1 = Attribute(
    ns.ns1 / "attr1",
    SchemaType.string,
    Cardinality.one
  ).withDoc("attr1")

  val ident1 = AddIdent(ns.ns1 / "ident1")
  val txDataA: Seq[TxData] = Seq(attr1)
  val txDataB: Seq[TxData] = Seq(ident1)
}
```

The exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at datomisca.Attribute.toAddOps$lzycompute(Attribute.scala:80)
    at datomisca.Attribute.toAddOps(Attribute.scala:78)
    at datomisca.Attribute.toTxData(Attribute.scala:98)
    at datomisca.Connection$$anonfun$transact$extension$1.apply(Connection.scala:152)
    at datomisca.Connection$$anonfun$transact$extension$1.apply(Connection.scala:151)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at datomisca.Connection$.transact$extension(Connection.scala:151)
    at datomisca.TransactOps$class.transact(TransactOps.scala:53)
    at datomisca.Datomic$.transact(Datomic.scala:31)
```

Transacting `Schema.txDataB` instead of `Schema.txDataA` however works fine. So it seems the error has something to do with Datomisca's `Attribute()`.

What's the problem and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a scala version issue.

Originally, I used the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dwhjames</groupId>
        <artifactId>datomisca_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Changing `artifactId` to "datomisca_2.10" fixed it for me.